# why my published app wont shows upp in google play/butik

Tags: google-play

i have uploaded an app to google play but after two days stil cant find it available to download.
i dont know if there is any problem with my AndroidManifest.xml but here come my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.PforD.remmember.me"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".Home"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="webbadd"></activity>
    <activity android:name="db_web_show"></activity>
    <activity android:name="who_is_this"></activity>
    <activity android:name="help_show"></activity>
    <activity android:name="request_answer"></activity>
    <activity android:name="delete"></activity>
</application>
```

thx for any help
reg.

Comment: i could found it by searching my name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It  should be up there , I was able to find my app after some 6-8 hrs I think

You can manually search

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.lockerz.compare

replace org.lockerz.compare   with your package name and try opening the link

Comment: i have figured out that by searching my name.